# virtuemart 2 - how to send invoice as email attachment on confirm order

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I want to send invoice as email attachment on order confirmation ,how to go about sending the invoice.
searched a lot ,not relevant data found.

Answer (score 0):

The VM Order Confirmation Email work flow is as follows,

Check the function `notifyCustomer()` inside `orders.php` in `administrator/components/com_virtuemart/models/`

There is a section like `shopFunctionsF::renderMail()` It calls a function from `shopefunctionsf` helper file in `/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/shopfunctionsf.php`

`renderMail()`  calls `sendVmMail()` in the same file there you can find option for attaching media or anything you want .

```
if (isset($view->mediaToSend)) {
            foreach ((array)$view->mediaToSend as $media) {
                //Todo test and such things.
                $mailer->addAttachment($media);
            }
        }
```

Hope its helps..

Comment: do you have idea how to add product image to invoice pdf that is generated?

Comment: check the invoice.php controller in front-end it have a function checkStoreInvoice() it create an HTML template that is converted to PDF do your stuff with HTML creation section .

Comment: there is no such function! and i want ass product image that user orders to pdf that is generated

Comment: Which file you have checked components/com_virtuemart/controllers/invoice.php have checkStoreInvoice()

Comment: ya same file it doesn't have that function

Comment: virtuemart 2 (2.0.26d)